# Interchangeable role of producer consumer threads in Java Multithreaded Program

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

**Objective** : To create two threads such that producer and consumer threads work interchangeably i.e if first thread acts as producer than second act as consumer and vice versa.

**Details** : They communicate with each other through a buffer,Storing one integer size. For example if first thread produces 1 then second thread consumes it and produces 2 and then the first thread consumes 2 and produces next three integers and Consumer consumes them one by one.
Both threads terminate after that.
Also both threads should be able to initiate the communication.

I tried to write the following code.

```
import java.util.Random;
class CommonItem {
boolean flag = false;
int arr[];

public synchronized void Send(String msg) {
    if (flag) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
    flag = true;
    notify();
}

public synchronized void Receive(String msg) {
    if (!flag) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(msg);
    arr = send_random();
    for (int item: arr) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    flag = false;
    notify();
}

synchronized int[] send_random(){
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    Random random= new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i]=random.nextInt(100);
    }
    return arr;
}
}
class T1 implements Runnable {
CommonItem Ci;

public T1(CommonItem Ci) {
    this.Ci = Ci;
    new Thread(this, "producer").start();
}

public void run() {
    while (true)
    Ci.Send("sent :1");
}
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
CommonItem Ci;

public T2(CommonItem m2) {
    this.Ci = m2;
    new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
}

public void run() {
    while (true)
    Ci.Receive("received :2");
}
}
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CommonItem m = new CommonItem();
    new T1(m);
    new T2(m);
}
}
```

The expected output is

```
sent :1

received :1

sent :2

received :2

sent :57 4 13

received :57 4 13
```

But I get the following output 
**OUTPUT**

```
sent :1

received :2

57

4

13
```

**Please suggest if any correction in the code or any idea on how to solve the given problem in an alternate way. Thank you in advance.**

Comment: How you use wait is wrong. See the oracle tutorial, also i have multiple SO answers about it. Also putting the locking code in the tasks as opposed to putting it in the common data structure seems like a bad idea; you took something that should be simple and made it complex. Also disregarding code conventions is not good.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CommonItem {
    boolean receiver = false;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void receive() throws InterruptedException {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        synchronized (list) {
            while (list.isEmpty()) {
                list.notify();
                list.wait();
            }

            // Receive all elements
            System.out.printf("Receiving elements by %s:\t", name);
            for (int val : list) {
                System.out.print(val + "  ");
            }
            list.clear();
            System.out.println();
            list.notify();
            list.wait();
        }
    }

    public void send() throws InterruptedException {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        synchronized (list) {
            while (!list.isEmpty()) {
                list.notify();
                list.wait();
            }
            // Sending elements
            int[] arr = get_random();
            System.out.printf("Sending elements by %s\t", name);
            for (int ele : arr) {
                list.add(ele);
                System.out.print(ele + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            list.notify();
            list.wait();
        }
    }

    public int[] get_random() throws InterruptedException {
        int[] arr = new int[3];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return arr;
    }
}

public class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    private CommonItem item;
    private boolean receiver;

    public ThreadTask(CommonItem item, boolean receiver) {
        this.item = item;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommonItem item = new CommonItem();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTask(item, false), "First");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTask(item, true), "Second");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (receiver) {
                    item.receive();
                } else {
                    item.send();
                }
                receiver = !receiver;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Sending elements by First 25  6  57
>   Receiving elements by Second:   25  6  57
>   Sending elements by Second  35  99  10
>   Receiving elements by First:    35  99  10
>   Sending elements by First   84  11  1
>   Receiving elements by Second:   84  11  1
>   Sending elements by Second  68  91  53
>   Receiving elements by First:    68  91  53

Comment: Thank you. I got the solution.

Comment: No problem... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
package java11;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
class CommonItem 
{
    boolean receiver = false;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int k=1;
    public void receive() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        synchronized (list) 
        {
            while (list.isEmpty()) 
            {
                list.notify();
                list.wait();
            }
            // Receive all elements
            System.out.printf("Receiving elements by %s:\t", name);
            for (int val : list) 
            {
                System.out.print(val + "  ");
            }
            list.clear();
            System.out.println();
            list.notify();
            list.wait();
        }
    }

    public void send(int i) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        synchronized (list) 
        {
            while (!list.isEmpty()) 
            {
                list.notify();
                list.wait();
            }
            // Sending elements
            int[] arr;
            if(i<3)
            {
                arr = get_random(k);
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr = get_random1();
            }
            System.out.printf("Sending elements by %s\t", name);
            for (int ele : arr) 
            {
                list.add(ele);
                System.out.print(ele + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            list.notify();
            list.wait();
        }
    }

    public int[] get_random(int k) throws InterruptedException  
    {
        int[] arr = new int[1];
        arr[0] = k;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return arr;
    }

    public int[] get_random1() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        int[] arr = new int[3];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return arr;
    }
}

public class Java11 implements Runnable 
{
    private CommonItem item;
    private boolean receiver;

    public Java11(CommonItem item, boolean receiver) 
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int choice;
        CommonItem item = new CommonItem();
        System.out.println("Who should start first?:Thread 1 or Thread 2");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        choice=sc.nextInt();
        if(choice==1)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Java11(item, false), "First");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Java11(item, true), "Second");
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Java11(item, true), "First");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Java11(item, false), "Second");
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        int i=1;
        while (i<=3) 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (receiver) 
                {
                    item.receive();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    item.send(i);
                }
                receiver = !receiver;
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Slight changes are made in Sanit's code to get exact output as demanded by the problem statement.

***OUTPUT:***

```
Who should start first?:Thread 1 or Thread 2
1
Sending elements by First   1  
Receiving elements by Second:   1  
Sending elements by Second  2  
Receiving elements by First:    2  
Sending elements by First   90  95  28  
Receiving elements by Second:   90  95  28  

Who should start first?:Thread 1 or Thread 2
2
Sending elements by Second  1  
Receiving elements by First:    1  
Sending elements by First   2  
Receiving elements by Second:   2  
Sending elements by Second  42  10  33  
Receiving elements by First:    42  10  33
```

Thank you @Sanit.

**Solved- @Kunjan Rana**

Comment: Note here that communication between the two threads starts by sending 1.